# Return 0 for 'subscript out of bounds error'

Tags: r, matrix, error-handling

Is there a simple way to deal with the “subscript out of bounds” error. I’d like to return 0 where this occurs, instead of having the error interrupt the code.

I understand the nature of the error in my context and it’s a perfectly legitimate finding that I'd like to report:
•   I’m capturing the difference between two data items.
•   So if e.g. there are 0 instance of case "a" (which might be where the difference is 0) then I get the subscript out of bounds error when looking up the matrix row name equal to “a”, whereas I’d like to report this finding as 0.

In the following simplified example, both CASE 1 and CASE 2 occur across my various matrices, but CASE 2 returns the 'subscript out of bounds' error.

```
    # CASE 1
    distribution <- matrix(c(1:12),  nrow=12, ncol=1)
    rownames(distribution) <- letters[1:12]
    distribution["a",]
    # CASE 2
    distribution <- matrix(c(1:11),  nrow=11, ncol=1)
    rownames(distribution) <- letters[2:12]
    distribution["a",]
```

and want to report the finding...

```
distribution["a",]
```

...for each of my matrices.

Something equivalent to the iferror formula in excel is what I'm after I guess.

Any thoughts / alternative suggestion to the problem are much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at `failwith`.

Comment: You could use something like `b<-try(distribution["a",])` and then check the class of `b` - `b<-ifelse(class(b)=="try-error",0,b)`.